How to create sliding-up-panel above bottom-tab-navigator in react native?
I tried up rn-sliding-up-panel but I am not desired results. To draw a clear picture, I want the UI similar to YouTube music, where mini player can drag to player screen. I tried to refer some video, but that didn't work for me. In the video, they were using floating button which navigates to player screen.
So, can you help me to create sliding-up-panel above bottom-tab-navigator such that panel can dragged to open in any bottom tab screens.

you can create a custom component by using this. it will provide you all the props you need. you can adjust according to your need.

You can easily create a sliding bottom sheet but going through this _post .By using this dependency you can easily achieve what you need. You can even see an example clip of an audio player which is similar according to your need.
